# How to configure Android Studio project to use actual source instead of decompiled?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, when I use the IDE shortcut (ctrl + click) to open a Class(from module A to a class in module B), I expect the .java file for that class to be opened. If the Class I click on is not in the same module it will take me to a decompiled version of that class.

`compile project(':moduleB')`

I am curious if is there a manner to link the classes to the source code in its respective module with just **Gradle** configuration **instead of the manual way** `Choose Sources...`?

[image]

Comment: do you have a `settings.gradle` file?

Comment: Yes I do `include ':moduleB', ':moduleC'`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a workaround to solve my problem, not sure if it's the best way to solve this, but it works for me. I'm open to hear a better approach.

In my **moduleA** `build.gradle` file I created a array with all my module name dependencies:

`def moduleNames = ['moduleB', 'moduleC', ...]`

Then I configured my sourceSets with my modules source folders:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        moduleNames.each {
            main.java.srcDirs += "$rootDir/$it/src/main/java/"
            androidTest.java.srcDirs += "$rootDir/$it/src/androidTest/java/"
            test.java.srcDirs += "$rootDir/$it/src/test/java/"
        }
    }
}
```

And finally I compile my modules with:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    moduleNames.each { compile project(":$it") }
}
```

**UPDATE**

My problem was that I was using a `moduleC` that was using `moduleB` too. So Android Studio tried to show me the compiled version. I finally fixed with these lines:

```
compile(project(':moduleC')) {
    exclude module: 'moduleB'
}
compile project(':moduleB')
```

Comment: After this my `moduleB` classes method are marked as `Method is never used` but they are actually used =/.

Comment: consider the `provided` method, instead of `compile`, as it will compile against, but not include, the dependency. (in moduleC, replace `compile project(':moduleB')` by `provided project(':moduleB')`)